# Negative rep score when neither question nor my answer were downvoted

Tags: support, reputation

My answer to this question- [Wood: A Naturally Occurring Composite Material?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/465753/wood-a-naturally-occurring-composite-material)

was green-checked as "accepted",  although neither the question nor my answer were upvoted (both show zero). However, my rep tally shows  a red -2 for my answer. Can anyone explain why this is so- was a user removed, for example?

Comment: What Rob says. Note that vote counts aren't displayed in the mobile view, so on a mobile device you need to click the "full site" button at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accept and the one upvote happened on March 10.  You can see them in your [reputation change history](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/40292/niels-nielsen?tab=reputation) on your profile page, where they earned you the usual +15 and +10 reputation points.

The change of -2 points is due to a downvote that appeared just today.

You may be able to see some of these details on the [post timeline](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/465761/timeline).  Note that you have also earned [the privilege of seeing vote counts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) in addition to the usual total score on a post.